# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova - Not signing APK

Tags: android, cordova, ant, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

As the question, I couldn't build a signed APK for Android.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a keystore file
2. Copied the keystore file to \res\native\android
3. Modified ant.properties with my keystore information
4. Build the project

Referred to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Project built successfully without any error, but I'm only getting xxx-unsigned.apk.

What could be wrong? It was working that way before I upgraded my OS to Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

If you hve update your client to cordova > 5 you have to make some changes to your project in order to run as expected.

For signing cordova tools for this version, use gadle instead ant so the old method doesn't work anymore. I use this:

1. Create a build.json on the project directory
2. Copy an paste this:

   {
       "android": {
           "release": {
               "keystore":"c:\my-release-key.keystore",
               "storePassword":"pwd123",
               "alias":"johnS",
               "password":"pwd123",
               "keystoreType":"",
           }
       }
   }
3. Put your credentials, and location of the keystore
4. Build

More [info](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/tutorial-package-publish)

Read the github documentation about other changes in web request and security you have to keep in mind in this new version of cordova.

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/Readme.md

Answer (score 0):

Do not select the ripple as your emulator. Select your target as actual device or any other proper emulator.